# Load init.q file at startup

Tags: kdb, q-lang

My `q.bat` file runs fine and it's contents are:

```
g:
cd \q
w32\q.exe %* -p 5000
```

Having defined some basic q functions in `init.q` file, I'd like to have them loaded and available every time I start kdb+/q.
I've tried including the below line at the end of the `q.bat` file, but it does nothing:

```
q init.q
```

I've read about other ways, like setting `QINIT` environmental variable or editing `q.q` file, but I suspect that loading via `.bat` is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `QINIT` or adding a `q.q` file is the correct method to load code into every q process.

However, if you want to load code into a selective number of q processes, this can be done via the following method:

Replace `w32\q.exe %* -p 5000` with `w32\q.exe init.q %*` (I've omitted the port, as you likely don't want all procs listening on the same port)

Within `init.q` you can execute the required init code for the process, this may involved

- Loading other q scripts (e.g `log.q` or `util.q` from some well known  directory)
- Handling command line args (`.z.x`), to initialise a specific process type. For example, given cmd line `q.bat rdb`, you can loda `rdb.q` and invoke `.rdb.init` function

Comment: Thank you. For a complete picture, what does `%*` mean?

Comment: Within a windows batch file `%*` provides all command line arguments supplied to the batch file - see http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true